# distinguish webhooks for test and live environment in the same developer account

Tags: docusignapi

Good day! I am trying to assign my docusign app to live status, but now I want to retain this account for staging environment too. I can create another app with another integration key. But I don't know how to distinguish 2 docusign webhooks for test and live environment in the same account by integration key. Could somebody provide me  any suggestions? How I can connect integration key and webhook for different environment?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using your Demo/Developer account for production data - envelope will be sent with the red "demonstration" watermark.

When you have a paid production account, I would recommend setting up your webhooks to run on different urls: Something like `example.com/webhook/test` vs `example.com/webhook/production`. Query String Parameters could be used instead if your application can parse them.

When an integration key is promoted to production, it is copied over, so it can still be used in the Demo environment. It is recommended that you keep your application running in the Demo environment so you can be aware of upcoming changes in the DocuSign platform.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check/accept the best answer to each of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Connect webhook is set on per account, your DEMO and Production accounts are separate entities. When you promote your ikey to production even the value is the same they are completely different. In production you still have to set your Secret Key and RSA Keypairs for the promoted ikey read here https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-from-the-trenches-your-apps-approved-for-go-live-now-configure-your-production-account
You can generate another ikey in sandbox, this is solution as well.

Comment: I have only one account and want to create 2 applications: one for production and another for test. I can create 2 webhooks, but I don't know how connect webhooks with the different applications.